# What design patterns fit this code smell?

Tags: design-patterns

I have a PDF form that has 450 fields in it and I'm going to fill it out using data that is in my Database.  Each field in the PDF has a unique name and I can do a mapping like:

```
switch (fieldname)
{
    case "Name":
        value = GetData(Name);
        break;  // Etc...
    case "Date":
        value = Date();
        break;
    default:
        value = "";
        break;
}
```

Now it seems like this is going to get very complex fast having 450 branches and if other documents get added it could grow massively.  What are the potential patterns that are available to solve this kind of problem?  Essentially I want to bind the PDF fields to the Database fields.

* EDIT ***
So lets just say that I have a giant switch statement ~450 branches, that routes PDF field names like 'Name' 'Address' 'Phone' to the correct database query for execution.  What other ways can I solve this other than switching on the field names when the field names are variable depending on which document was selected by the end user.

* FINAL EDIT ***
I thought about it for a day and came up with solution thanks to all the suggestions.  I have a function called GetElement().  It takes the PDF field name as a parameter and executes a stored procedure that returns the database column and another procedure name as a map.  Then using some dynamic SQL I pass the procedure name and column i'm looking for and return the results.  Hard to pick the right answer here but I'll give credit to the one that pushed me the closest.

Comment: Loops perhaps? Or are you just not including them in your code snippet?

Comment: What do you mean by "fill it out"? Why are you writing all data into the variable value? Furthermore, are you really looking for a design pattern or rather a tool or technique for querying / database handling?

Comment: I'm using the data from the database to populate the PDF document.  So if there is a place called 'Name' in the PDF document I'll return the appropriate name from the database and write it to the document.  I've got the tools currently Linq2Sql and iTextSharp for getting the data and writing to the PDF.  All working, I can just see this monster switch statement routing data from the database to the documents and it scares me =\

Comment: As jamWaffles said use a loop. foreach( $fields as $field ) $field['value'] = GetData( $field );

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder in this case it seems you have passed the routing problem to GetData() which will need a similar amount of branching.

Comment: @JamWaffles correct this is wrapped by in a loop.  The crux of the problem is the mapping of the data.  There's multiple documents with multiple fields and I am iterating over them all.

Comment: If you're putting this data in a table, you can just loop through each row printing the appropriate `<tr>` and `<td>` elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what little I know about your overall problem, it seems it would be easiest to store the field name along with the value in the DB.  It's a simple name-value pair looping structure then, and you don't hard code name strings in your code that way either.  More generic?  Hope this helps.

Comment: I can see where storing the field names in the database would be helpful, but what if the values are variable depending on user input?  And how would you retrieve them from the application without using a big switch/if else based on what's stored in the db?

Comment: Now we are seeing the devil in the details.   User input was not mentioned in your OP.  :)  You said, "... I'm going to fill it out using data that is in my Database."

Comment: Thanks Joe,  I edited the first post.  Hope that was somewhat helpful.  The user input I'm talking about is the document that they can select.  Depending on the document the 'field' names will be different.

Comment: I think this solution can work with varying field names depending on document... you just need to add document name to the equation by storing which field names are in which document

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to implement a Object-Property-Value system, the object here is a document which has various properties... having different values in different instances.

It's a very common model but best to be persisted in a storage other than a conventional RDBMS, maybe an xml database.

Comment: Or a noSQL database like couchDB or any other type of document based database. Heck you can even use git and file systems as a database for that

Answer (score 1):

More than a design pattern I would go for a simpler approach, correct me if I made wrong assumptions:

- You have different types of documents, each one with a different mapping.
- During the application user can select any of those documents
- The mapping of a document can change and new documents can be added

One option would be to have a series of maps (with key,value pairs), that hold the configuration of the document.

The maps would initialized when the application is started from some configuration files (some properties or xml files), and the maps cached so you don't have to recreate them all the time.

When you process a document only have to choose the right map object and do a loop: `foreach($field in $document): $field['value'] = getData(pdfMap.getValue($field));`

If you need to change or add some configuration, just change the mapping files and restart the application (or update the map if you don't want to have to restart)

Answer (score 0):

As a structured Document I think [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) will be your best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not return all 450 data items from the database using a SELECT and then index into this using `fieldname`? Which language are you using?

eg

```
datarow dr = GetAllData();
foreach field in document {
  field.value = dr[field.Name];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You create your database table with same name as the pdf field name. You can then use this one to one mapping to fill values in you pdf file. I assume that all you set in you pdf are strings.

Another way:
If datatype is of concern, you will need a field->datatype mapping somewhere (say an ENUM in java). Then create one function called getValue(fieldName) which calls getString(fieldName) or getDate(fieldName) or getCurrency(fieldName) based on the data type.

Your switch case for a data type will be 5-10 at max.